mysql select based on latest date
I have a table with non-unique value and date on it
How to select values by the given tuple with the latest datetime?
given tuple (foo, bar)
result should be
[(1, foo, 2024-05-29 03:38:12),  (6, bar, 2024-05-29 08:36:14)]

 id     value   date
 1      foo     2024-05-29 03:38:12*
 2      foo     2024-05-27 12:37:06
 3      xxx     2024-05-29 08:17:24
 4      foo     2024-05-27 13:45:03
 5      bar     2024-05-28 12:56:04
 6      bar     2024-05-29 08:36:14*

I tried with the MAX(date) and GROUP BY, but seems my mysql level not that good to get a result((
Thank you

similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350684/sql-show-only-the-row-with-the-latest-date

On MySQL 8+ the ROW_NUMBER() window function provides one way to do this:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, value, date
FROM cte
WHERE value IN ('foo', 'bar') AND rn = 1;

Here is a version which would work on earlier versions of MySQL (5.7 and lower):
SELECT t1.id, t1.value, t1.date
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT value, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY value
) t2
    ON t2.value = t1.value AND
       t2.max_date = t1.date
WHERE
    t1.value IN ('foo', 'bar');


thank you, unfortunately I'm on MySQL 8-

@Alberto I have updated my answer with an option which should work on MySQL 5.7.

  SELECT t.id, t.value, t.date
FROM your_table t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT value, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY value
) AS latest ON t.value = latest.value AND t.date = latest.max_date;

SELECT value, MAX(date) AS max_date FROM your_table GROUP BY value: This subquery calculates the latest date for each value across the entire table.
SELECT t.id, t.value, t.date FROM your_table t: This is selecting the columns you are interested in from your table.
INNER JOIN (...subquery...) AS latest ON t.value = latest.value AND t.date = latest.max_date: This join ensures that you only get the rows that match the latest date for each value as found in the subquery.

SELECT value, MAX(date) AS max_date FROM your_table GROUP BY value - this is the simplest way and in my opinion the simpler the better. Many thanks all you guys for your time and answers
